# How to fix "Symbolizer buffer too small" warning?

Tags: c++, llvm, address-sanitizer

I am running a C++ binary compiled with clang-14 with `-fsanitize=address`. It complains about memory leaks:

```
=================================================================
==1367193==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 208 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
==1367193==WARNING: Symbolizer buffer too small
```

But as you can see there are numerous `Symbolizer buffer too small` warnings. I indeed can see how some of the reported stack frames are truncated to approx 3062 chars. But the real problem is stack trace seems corrupted - some functions are said to call functions they cannot call.

I wonder if this is related to the warning, and how do I fix it.

**UPD** Indeed the problem was in symbolizer. If I run the same binary with `ASAN_OPTIONS='symbolize=0'` as suggested below, I get smaller callstacks. If I run their addresses manually through `llvm-symbolizer` I get the proper function names. So it seems like symbolizer is not run properly from the sanitizer.

Comment: What if you run with: `ASAN_OPTIONS='symbolize=0' ./your_binary`  as suggested in [issue 1503](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1503)?

Comment: If I run with symbolizer I get two callstacks with depths of 45 and 55. If I run without symbolizer (`symbolize=0`) I get two callstacks with depths of 29 both and (obviously) no warnings. Hmm. Kind of sus.

Comment: Yeah, it seems suspect. You could try to compile without asan and then try valgrind to confirm that you actually don't have any leaks.